# How to solve no certificates found error in Android Ice Cream Sandwich while trying to add a Calendar in emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar, certificate, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to use the Calendar app of Android Ice Cream Sandwich. It wants me to add an account. While I am trying to add an account of mine to exchanged services, it says that no certificates found. My question is how can I find and add this certificates to the emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I created my own SSL key. But I realized that there was a next button at the bottom of the emulator screen. I was clicking the select certificate button which is the only visible button :) Anyway, by writing in domain/username -> / name @hotmail.com and server -> m.hotmail.com, I resolved the problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.  I simply selected "Accept all SSL certificates" and it works.  However, the Ice Cream Sandwich emulator does not seem to support gmail account properly.  Which is very unexpected.

Comment: If you write as below, you can connect your gmail account. domain/username: / _name_ @gmail.com server: m.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://mavenlog.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/how-to-adding-a-calendar-in-the-android-ics-emulator/
It is detailed and well-illustrated with screenshots.
I have tried it and it works without certificates.